# PEAR claims php was compiled with old module

Tags: php, xdebug, pear, pecl

I just upgraded to php 5.6.4. When i do pear installs of various packages it complains that if have a module mismatch.

example:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
Failed loading /usr/local/php-5.6.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so:
/usr/local/php-5.6.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_execute_ex
Zend OPcache requires Zend Engine API version 220131226.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is outdated.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: PDFlib: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
```

However, 20131226 is php 5.6.4, 20100525 is 5.4 i believe. So oddly pear thinks the modules were compiled w/ 5.6 but the version of php is 5.4. Ive had this the other way around where the module is older than the php version a lot and typically just recompile those module. this one im a bit stumped.

```
[richv]$ php -v
PHP 5.6.4 (cli) (built: Jun 16 2015 16:08:30)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

[richv]$ pear version
PEAR Version: 1.9.5
PHP Version: 5.6.4
Zend Engine Version: 2.6.0
Running on: Linux dragon 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 13 10:06:09 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the old php version lying around, then pear/pecl probably still uses this php version - even if it shows the correct php version in `pear version`.

Try to change the `php_bin` pear config setting:

```
$ pear config-show
..
$ pear config-set php_bin /path/to/new/php
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track. Old version of pear that when using sudo would be used. without sudo the accurate version was being used.